# How can I plot GPS coordinates on Google Map

Tags: google-maps, gps

What is the best way to plot GPS coordinates on a Google Map?

Are there any tools that can do that (written in python specifically)?

Comment: Are you interested in speaking to the GPS directly, or you have a GPX or equivalent file you'd like to convert?

Comment: Please fix the typo in the question; it's disrupting my sense of balance in the universe ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python as asked (Convert GPS .gpx to KML)
gpx2kml—Simple Python program to convert a GPX file to a Google Maps KML file 
http://beej.us/gps/

Then use

var ctaLayer = new **google.maps.KmlLayer**('http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml');
  ctaLayer.setMap(map);
}

Example for Google Maps API v3
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml.html

Comment: Awesome. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a lot of tools and ways for doing this. You didn't specify in which format you have GPS coordinates so i will assume that they are in downloaded from GPS device in gpx format. If that's the case, you can use [online converter](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/map_input?form=googleearth) to kml and then display kml on to Google Map or you can use this [tool](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/map_input?form=google).

If you would like to use python you can use [GDAL/OGR lib](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython) to convert almost any format to desired one, in your case probably kml.

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/

Or if it doesn't have to be Google try a custom online mapping application like Geocommons